# Concatenate String using '+' in Android

Tags: java, android, string, string-concatenation

I am implementing toString method (Android) that I need to concatenate all fields in an object

For Java (JDK) I can do as below:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{_id=" + _id + 
            ", name=" + name +  
            "}";        
}
```

Behind the scene, Java Compiler will use StringBuilder to build String concatenation for me so I don't have to use StringBuilder explicitly.

**My question is: Can I use this implementation way in ANDROID code. OR I have to use StringBuilder explicitly?** I don't know how Android Compilier work for this case.

Anyone has any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to do that in Android? It's the same thing.

Comment: yes.. you can use it in the same way..

Comment: This looks like you're build a SQL query string.  In that case, do NOT use this.  Use bind variables.  Using this method risks SQL injection bugs, and it doesn't let the db optimize as well.

Comment: If you are building a SQL string, remind that this: `", name=" + name + "}";` should read so `", name='" + name + "'}";` (surround your strings with apostrophes). However, it's better to **bind** your parameters, as @GabeSechan correctly pointed out.

Comment: @GabeSechan,@Frank N. Stein: I am not building dynamic SQL. I am implementing toString object. You are right for SQL query builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in Android. Whether it will be optimized in the same way is down to the specific compiler and JVM you are using but its very rare to find one that will not optimize that any more.

Comment: You mean Android Compiler will convert my code to StringBuilder for optimization?

Comment: I mean that most Java Compilers will do so, including the Android ones (since the Android compilers are mostly standard Java Compilers with a different set of libraries). There is no guarantee for all compilers and JVMs though.